# Java mail going to Junk mail for distribution list group mail id

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send mail using Java mail to distribution list(group mail id) and its a success. but thing is its recieved in junk box in MS Outlook by default. How to make it been delivered to Inbox?

Mail from donotreply@.com should be delivered to Inbox.

```
    String host = "SMARTHOST.XXXX.COM";
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(PDFGenerator.propLoad());
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host); // smtp.gmail.com?
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    // From e-mail Id
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("donotreply@example.com"));
    message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, "groupmailId@example.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

In outlook add the sender's email to the safe senders list.  This has nothing to do with java, sendmail, etc...  It has to do with a spam filter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..but when we trigger ant mail for the same distribution list its working fine.only for java mail we are facing this issue.

Comment: Compare the headers in the two cases to figure out what's different.  Your spam filter is probably triggering based on some difference in the headers or the message content.

Comment: Javamail allows you to set most header elements.